# Extract set number of characters after specific word in string

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to extract a 'Month, year' substring from a larger string. An example would be:

`12345 October, 2019, abc, abcdef`

although the length and complexity of the strings surrounding the substring do vary from one record to the next. There will only ever be one 'month, year' substring per string.

So far I have been able to extract the month aspect using the following code:

```
months <- paste(c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), collapse = "|")
str_extract_all("12345 October, 2019, abc, abcdef",months, simplify = FALSE)
```

While this requires typing out all the months of the year, I don't really want to have to specify every year possible in a similar vector.
Is there a way of extracting a set number of characters after a matched string? As in, extract any matching word from the month vector, as well as the next 6 characters (the ', 2019' portion).

Comment: E.g., in the most general form, `str_extract_all("12345 October, 2019, abc, abcdef", paste0("(?:",months, "),\\s*\\d{4}\\b"), simplify = FALSE)` but it depends on your data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect, thanks